QucsStudio RF power amplifier simulation
I am simulating a circuit with Mitsubishi RF power amplifier (RD02LUS2) in QucsStudio 4.3.1. The schematics provided by Mitsubishi is as follows.

The above circuit is matched for 400MHz - 470MHz.
When I try to simulate the above schematics in QucsStudio, I get matching around 530MHz, that too not a good matching.

Any idea where am I doing wrong?
Link to datasheet: https://www.mitsubishielectric.com/semiconductors/hf/products/datasheet/rd02lus2.pdf
Link to .s2p file: https://www.mitsubishielectric.com/semiconductors/hf/products/parameters/rd02lus2_3.6v_140ma.s2p
Link to my QucsStudio file: https://surfdrive.surf.nl/files/index.php/s/VRQDQR8xTaLhNOV

S-parameters are for small signal use and are not very useful in large signal applications like power amplifiers. The datasheet gives the neccessary transistor source and load impedances for use in the shown UHF 2W power amplifier test circuit. If you compare this to the impedances provided with the S2P file you will see that these are not on par.
Remove the MOSFET from the circuit and measure into the input and output matching networks while loaded with 50 Ohm. Idealy you will get the conjugate complex values of the values shown in the datasheet.
--- EDIT ---
Adjustments made to the output matching network to make it work in the 400...470MHz range. Transmission lines were calculated for a 0.8mm FR4 board with Er=4.6. The achieved load impedances are:
@ 400MHz: Z = 2.05 - j2.01
@ 435MHz: Z = 2.15 - j1.12
@ 470MHz: Z = 2.37 - j0.36


Thank you for the explanation. I will try it

I removed the two port network and terminated with the complex conjugate mentioned in datasheet. I got the matching between 480 and 520MHz instead of 400 - 470MHz

Considering it's an application circuit from a datasheet, you have to take it with a grain of salt. I don't think it is really intended to be replicated 1:1, but rather to be seen as an example how it could be done. Nonetheless I took a look at the output matching network and with small adjustments I got close enough to the optimal load impedances for UHF stated in the datasheet.
